# Is there a smart way to catch a list with all elements set to integer(0) in R?

Tags: r

Suppose you have a list where each element is an integer(0). How can you catch this "error" in an effective way?

```
# Reproducible example
set.seed(10)
a <- list(a = as.factor(integer(0)), b = as.factor(sample(letters[1:5], 10, rep=T)))
levels(a$a) <- levels(a$b)
a$b <- as.factor(integer(0))
levels(a$b) <- levels(a$a)
a

# I know I can catch an integer(0) using length()
length(integer(0))

# But how can I check that all list elements are integer(0)???
```

The only case I'd like to catch is the one where all the elements of the list are integer(0).

Answer (score 3):

This will check that the length of every list element is 0:

```
all(lengths(a) == 0)
```

It won't differentiate between `numeric(0)`, `integer(0)`, `character(0)`, etc.

If the `integer` part important, You might have some  like in your example), but you could make another check: `all(sapply(a, typeof) == "integer")` if you only want `integer(0)`s.

Comment: No. Ideally it would check for both integer(0), factor(0) and numeric(0)  but it isn't necessary to know which one it is.

Comment: maybe better use `typeof` than class ?